# Hide elements on the page in webview Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I want to load the site , but do not want to show `divHeader` , I've tried several ways and apparently the code I'm using does not have mistakes because there are no messages in `logcat` ... How do I hide a particular Div.

```
package br.webview.com;


import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;   


    public class WebViewDevMobileActivity extends Activity {

        private WebView myWebView;

        private final String URL = "http://uniceu.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/";

        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.site);

            if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {

                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opa, parece que vc esta sem internet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {  

            myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);         
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
            {  
                @Override  
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
                {  
                    myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
                            "document.getElementById('divHeader')[0].style.display='none'; " +  
                            "})()");  
                }  
            });  

            myWebView.loadUrl(URL);
            myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                myWebView.goBack();
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }    
}   
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementById()` returns single Node element. Try:

```
document.getElementById('divHeader').style.display='none'
```

To manipulate multiple elements would be better to add additional class to elements that should be hidden in WebView (`__hiddenInWebView` in this case), and then:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.__hiddenInWebView');
for (index in items) {
    items[index].style.display = 'none';
}
```

if You can't modify DOM from webpage (add additional classes), then populate array with elements and hide them in a loop:

```
var items = [];
items.push(document.querySelector('#first'));
items.push(document.querySelector('#second'));
for (index in items) {
    items[index].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Excellent , it worked very well what the correct syntax for I hide two elements ?

Comment: How to apply this in my code? I did not understand the application.

Comment: `"document.getElementById('divHeader')[0].style.display='none'; "` this is Your JS code. Just replace ir with JS code from my answer. If You are not familiar with JS then emm, `querySelector()` selects element (one element, first in DOM) from Your HTML page using CSS selector (`querySelector('#divHeader')` is the same as `getElementById('divHeader')` just `#` indicates that this is an ID).

Comment: Like This? myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
                            "var items = [];" + 
"items.push(document.querySelector('#divHeader'));" + 
"items.push(document.querySelector('#mapCanvas'));" + 
"for (index in items) {" + 
 "items[index].style.display = 'none';" + 
} " +  
                            "})()");

Comment: Is not rolling , is giving a lot of token errors expected , BlockStatements , sending delete the "=" , sorry to bother you so much, but not even understand the exchange that block of code for this , sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112540/discussion-between-bogdan-kustan-and-paulo-roberto).

Answer (score -1):

is it not possible to just reference the ID of the object then set it to visible false

```
 aq.id(R.id.divHeader).visibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

also try using findViewById , to achieve the same effect

Comment: He is asking about embeded HTML id's, not android view XML